# Не выводить строку в шаблоне

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется шаблон для wordpress, в котором выводится количество комментариев, перед постами следующим кодом:

```
<a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" class="link-comments"><?php comments_number("0 ".__('Comments','theme'), "1 ".__('Comment','theme'), "% ".__('comments','theme')); ?></a>
```

Как изменить его, что бы при 0 не выводилось вообще ничего (сейчас выводится 0 Comments соответственно).

*Только начинаю разбираться

Comment: заменить "0 ".__('Comments','theme') на пустую строку "" как вариант

Comment: если заменить 'Comments','theme' на ' ', ' ' тогда будет выводиться 0, что не нужно

Comment: а если "0 ".__('Comments','theme'), 0 то отсюда "0 "

Comment: вот из codex более наглядный пример использования функции <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?>.

Answer (score 1):

Можете обернуть ваш код проверкой на наличие комментариев:

```
<?php if (get_comments_number( $post_id )): ?>
    <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" class="link-comments"><?php comments_number("0 " . __('Comments', 'theme'),
            "1 " . __('Comment', 'theme'), "% " . __('comments', 'theme')); ?></a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Фунция [get_comments_number()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) не требует параметра, если выполняется в цикле, иначе нужно указать id записи.

Либо, как уже указал kandellak:

```
<?php comments_number("", "1 " . __('Comment', 'theme'), "% " . __('comments', 'theme')); ?>
```